# USB C or other compact connector for 19 identical, general purpose lines?

Tags: usb, connector, wiring

I'm building an LED lighting system that requires around 16 connections to an Arduino (15 LED power supplies plus a common ground line), and I want to clean up the cabling. It's important for my application that the connector at the ends of any cabling be small and neat.

Essentially I would love to use a USB C cable – without any of the internal chips/resistors – simply to carry 19 identical general purpose wires. Then I could use standard USB C breakout boards at each end of the cable, and use the USB C cable as a simple wire conduit with nice connectors.

For all my searching, I can't find anything like this...

Does something like this exist? Is there an obvious solution to this problem that I am failing to see? Perhaps a different type of common connector that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: There is no such thing, because USB-C has only a maximum of 13 wires plus power and shielding.

Comment: I thought 19 wires... No? Does power take up the remaining 6?

Comment: Yes, Full-featured USB 3.1 Type-C cable should have 19 conductors, if you count the shield. Not all of them identical though. "Does something like this exist?" does what exist? You've said yourself "standard USB C breakout board". A quick search on google for "usb c breakout" gives dozens of [these](https://www.banggood.com/Type-C-Female-Connector-USB-3_1-Adapter-Plug-Socket-SMT-Type-Test-Module-p-1032350.html).

Comment: Great! Yes, these are the breakout boards I was referring to. But the problem is the cable itself— don't the cables themselves contain circuitry at the base of each connector conferring special performance to each wire?

Comment: Yes, they do. That is why I said they are not identical wires. I believe at least 16 wires are pass-trough, though. But frankly, this is most cumbersome and quite expensive solution. Why don't you use I2C switch chip, some mosfets and resistors and any suitable 5 conduits cable?

Comment: Does "pass through" mean "it's just a copper wire" and nothing special happens? i.e. I could route 5V along those pass through wires, and I'd just get 5V out the other end?

Comment: @Maple There is no guarantee that the 8 power pins actually are separated in the cable. They could as well be connected together on only 2 wires. That's why I wrote 13 plus wires for power. There is no 19 in USB-C - I don't know how you count.

Comment: If these are "lighting" LEDs and not indicator LEDs you need to consider the power and resulting current.  That single shared ground return sounds problematic...   And do you really want to bunch all off the lights into one connector?   In many cases a better solution would be one connector *per* light and to build the Arduino's functionality into a board with 15 downstream connectors, or sit it behind a panel with that many bulkhead connectors.  Or potentially join them into smaller groups, say 5 of 3.

Comment: By "lighting" I'm talking about 100-1000mA at a maximum, and typically the usage case is one LED at a time. Also, 13 wires for power would actually be great in most instances!

Comment: Do you folks ever read any specifications? https://cambrionix.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/USB-Type-C-Specification-Release-1.3.pdf

Comment: @asdfex You are correct, one cannot use power pins separately. But not for the reason you state, i.e. only two actual wires. The reason is "All VBUS pins shall be connected together within the USB Type-C plug" and same for  Ground. That still leaves 16 pass-through, just as I said above.

Comment: @AliChen I can practically taste your pain reading your comment

Comment: @MarcusMüller I believe the pain comes not from people not reading documentation but trying to hammer a nail with a microscope.

Comment: @Maple Nah, "hammering" is the appropriate thing to do – I think (not necessarily in this case, but in general) the pain is more because people ask how to mine for fish using Altium Designer 4 on a raspberry pi.

Comment: @Maple The standard explicitly asks for 1 power wire - but that is a suggestion and everybody can do as they like. And no, it's not 16 pass-through, as Vconn must not tie both ends of the cable together.

Comment: please draw a diagram of what you are trying to build ..... this sounds like it may cause problems `15 LED power supplies plus a common ground line`

Comment: @ChrisStratton Typically I want to cycle through the LEDs one at a time, but I can imagine a case where it would be nice to have all LEDs on at the same time. When you say the shared ground sounds problematic, is that because you are thinking a USB connector would be too thin to handle the total amperage? I ask this because all the wonderful answers in this thread have basically convinced me to go with a D sub mini or similar, and the wires in this kind of connector can be as hefty as I need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**19** you say?

By coincidence, HDMI does have exactly nineteen conductors.

But: three of them are shields, some are differential pairs, which are optimized for high-frequency signals instead of low-frequency current transport… I doubt a single one of them was designed to carry current for a 20 mA LED, leave alone a "power LED" (whatever that is).

In short: all these modern computer cables are specialty devices and you can't expect them to just be "a bunch of wires".

So, stick with something else. SUB-D connectors are pretty standard, and they are easy to deal with with hand tools; of course, they are a lot larger. But you might need that anyway, because "power LED" kind of says each conductor might carry 1 A or more, and that's not going to be fun with smaller connectors...

If you asked me, this sounds like an architectural thing: Instead of buying (expensively) copper to bridge a large distance with a lot of current (losing power to wire resistance), you should probably have your (or another) Arduino where you'd  have the other end of that cable you're wishing for, and just run a data line and power there.

In fact, there's really easy ways to switch a lot of outputs with few cables:

For example, there's linear shift registers with a latch input; there's even some that come with integrated linear LED drivers with adjustable current. With these, you'd only have to run 5 signals

- power
- Ground
- Data
- CLK
- Latch (optional)

That sounds a lot easier and less error-prone then having 19 conductors! Also, you're not limited to 15 LEDs that way. You can have as many as you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for these insights! I'm reading about shift registers now and I may come back with a follow up once I'm on top of that :)

Comment: Ask a new question instead as you will be changing the topic.

Comment: Using shift registers looks to be a great idea in general, and I may implement this. But my primary use case it's to switch each LED on/off one at a time, and I want to be able to do this core strobing function quite quickly (strobing each LED on/off at say 1kHz). I'm worried that most shift registers would introduce too much latency for this to be achievable, so building that into the core lighting system seems dangerous. That leaves me still needing to route conductors to each LED independently :(

Comment: Are you strobing them to dim them? Because there's dedicated ICs that can do that, for exactly this use case!

Comment: (Switching rapidly off and on can be quite a bad idea over long cable, anyway!)

Comment: The strobing is to synchronise with other equipment— I'll be using PWM or a digital-analog converter circuit (for "true" dimming) to modulate intensity. I'm more likely to want to strobe them one by one at about 0.1kHz, now that I think of it. And my cabling should be less than 1m, so I was hoping I'd be okay!

Comment: yeah, ok, 100 Hz is likely to be OK, really. So, still, maybe just use a microcontroller close to the LEDs, and just communicate with that over 1m.

Answer (score 1):

The standard "full-featured" USB 3.0 cable has <strike>18 conductors</strike> 15 conductors, optionally 3 more, and one shield. It is defined in [Type-C Specification](https://cambrionix.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/USB-Type-C-Specification-Release-1.3.pdf), see Table 3-6

[image]

See also the footnote. The wires are not "identical general purpose wires", some  are either coaxial, or twisted in pairs.

Also it is important to remember that if the cable is implemented as twisted pairs (the majority are), simple use of wires for digital signaling purposes might result in huge cross-talk.

More, some signal in cables might be using skinny AWG34 wires, see Table 3-8, so one needs to consider substantial wire impedance and limited ampacity.

Even more, expect that CC wire will have some IC attached (called "electronic marker"), and powered via Vconn wire. According to Type-C specifications, ALL full-featured cables must have electronic markers.

Comment: Thanks Ali, this is great. It's all adding up to a conclusion that I should probably move to a Micro D-Sub general purpose connector, and just accept the larger size. I really appreciate your answer— thanks :)

Comment: not "18 conductors and one shield", but "15 conductors, optionally 3 more and one shield"

Answer (score 1):

Led driver (e.g. [TLC59116](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc59116.pdf) for 16 x 120 mA channels, [IS31FL3236](http://www.issi.com/WW/pdf/31FL3236.pdf) for 36 x  38 mA channels) + 4-conductor cable is all you need.

Ironically, if your combined LED current is under 1A then good ol' USB 2.0 cable can work for you. Just don't use high speed clock, twisted pair has a lot of crosstalk.

For higher current simply use any suitable cable and just about any of thousands available connectors, like [DIN](https://www.cui.com/product/resource/sd.pdf) for example.

UPDATE

> The latency issue is because I might want to cycle each LED independently on/off at 1kHz (e.g. LED #1 on for 5ms, off, repeat at 1kHz)

As it happens, you misunderstand how these chips work. You don't need to generate PWM by yourself, you simply send commands that set individual LED brightness, and the chip generates PWM for you (at 97 kHz, or about 100 times faster than you were planning).

The whole point of this answer is that you don't have to control LEDs yourself, you use digital communication over few wires and tell the chip what to do. At 100 kHz clock speed you can change the brightness of all 15 LEDs about 700 times per second, or about 20 times faster than human can perceive.

> I have a Osram specs that indicate 3.1V forward voltage and a range (?) of 100-1000mA

Don't you think **this info belongs to the question?** And how were you going to use Type C cable (as in the title) if most of the wires in it are AWG34, with maximum rated current only 180 mA? Do you realize that with 1A per LED your ground wire will carry over 15A!

Anyway, in this case you still have multiple options available.

- You can use driver with open drain output, like 18 channel [LV5235V](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/ENA1941-D.PDF) and control external switch while limiting maximum current with a resistor (as I suggested in the comment to your question from the beginning).
- Or you can control constant-current driver with PWM input and suitable rating, like [CAT4101](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/CAT4101-D.PDF). This should be more efficient than using resistors.

[image]

- You can also use automotive shunt-type dimming chip, like [TPS92661](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps92661-q1.pdf) with external buck regulator e.g. [TPS92515x](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps92515hv-q1.pdf). This option is probably most power efficient, although it requires separate wire with about 40V to power 12 LEDs in series (or 2 wires for your 15 LEDs). The cool thing about this setup is that it trades high current for high voltage, so you can use *much thinner wires*.

The bottom line is: send control signal and provide power to your LED system, do the actual PWM switching by small circuit in the system itself.

BTW, with only 4-5 wires you probably don't even need "small and neat" connector on LED side, you can solder that end of the cable directly to PCB.

Comment: More great advice, thank you! I would be worried about two things here: 1) latency introduced by the drivers, and 2) maximum current. The latency issue is because I might want to cycle each LED independently on/off at 1kHz (e.g. LED #1 on for 5ms, off, repeat at 1kHz). The maximum current issue is because even with just one LED, I have a Osram specs that indicate 3.1V forward voltage and a range (?) of 100-1000mA (https://au.rs-online.com/mobile/p/visible-leds/1751875/). So I'm worried about building in a driver that may limit my options away from the device...

Comment: See update in the answer.

Comment: @Iams how are you even delivering 1000 mA from an arduino? You already have built some kind of driver, haven't you?

Comment: Lots more useful insights here, thanks again for taking the time! To be clear, the strobing isn't intended to effect dimming— it is for syncing with other equipment. For dimming I've been using simple PWM and have considered an analogue alternative to produce "true" dimming.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've already run some bulb-type 5mm LEDs in my application, but they take up too much space and I wanted to get a bit more brightness, so I'm considering a variety of different SMT options. Part of my problem is that when I look at e.g. those Osram specs, I see a current range (100-1000mA) and I don't have enough experience to know what would likely be required to get a decent LED intensity. RE: wire gauge, I originally assumed my requirements were fairly modest, but from this forum I'm getting the idea that these are considered fairly high powered SMT LEDs. Thanks again!

Comment: You will need some LED driver that can deliver that current and can be controlled by your Arduino! Your arduino's pins individually cannot even deliver 100 mA, leave alone 15× that in total (the chip would just burn if they did that). But, "how do I control 15 0.1 – 1A LEDs from a single Arduino, if these are 1m away" is a new question, and leaves the scope from this cable oriented question. So, post a new question, where you describe the components, link to the datasheet above, explain your requirements in detail, and ask how to solve this. Much more productive than trying to sort this out

Comment: in the comments to an answer to a different question about cables. (especially describing the syncing and why you need multiple watts of LED power to achieve that would be helpful)

Comment: Re: Strobbing, LV5235V chip has separate bit registers for direct on/off, PWM and fading functions. You can easily strobe all LEDs without changing individual PWM values as fast as 3.7 kHz at standard I2C speed.